# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to filter some crypto coins but it shows an error **"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')"**

```
const filteredCoins = coins.filter(coin => coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `coin.name` is nothing.

Comment: Following up on Mike's comment above - can you share the content of `coins`?

Comment: here @Mureinik https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false

Comment: If that's the content of `coins`, then `search` must be `undefined`?

Comment: ya I forget to put useState ("")

Comment: It could be that the API service is temporarily unavailable. Try adding: if (isFetching) return "Loading"; to run before your code.